# Why is there a dash across my variables

Tags: android

I am really new to android so pardon me. Why is there a strike-through

> for example (<strike>fill_parent</strike>)

in some android variables and not others

Comment: Highlight it in your IDE and it'll tell you. The reason is because its deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strikeout shows deprecated methods or attributes (assuming you are using Android Studio / IntelliJ). In your case FILL_PARENT (LayoutParams?) is deprecated for a really long time (API Level 8). It is now called MATCH_PARENT (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html). Hovering the variable should show you a tooltip with more information on the deprecation and when it was deprecated. Just make sure you don't use those deprecated elements.

Comment: Ahh i see. Thank you very much